# How to delete image after save using Bitmap object with Selenium c#?

Tags: c#, console, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium C# to take screenshots. Convert as Bitmap and then Save to specific path. After save complete. I want to delete that same screenshot. It doesn't allow me to delete and throw the file that is being used by another process.

Below is my code:

```cs
public Bitmap GetScreenshot(IWebDriver driver)
{
    //Take Screenshot
    Screenshot screenshot = (driver as ITakesScreenshot).GetScreenshot();
    //Convert Screenshot to Bitmap
    var img = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(screenshot.AsByteArray)) as Bitmap;            
    return img;
}
```

I used above function like this:

```cs
var img = GetScreenshot(driver);
seleniumExtras.SaveImageAsPDF(img, "fullpage.jpeg");
```

Here is the function **SaveImageAsPDF**:

```cs
public void SaveImageAsPDF(Bitmap imageData, string ImagePath)
{
    imageData.Save(ImagePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    imageData.Dispose();
    
    //Save as PDF
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(ImagePath);
    iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
    doc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(ImagePath.Replace(".jpeg", ".pdf"), FileMode.Create));
    doc.Open();
    iTextSharp.text.Image pdfImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    
    //pdfImage.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0); // set the position to bottom left corner of pdf
    pdfImage.ScaleAbsolute(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Width, iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Height); // set the height and width of image to PDF page size
    pdfImage.ScaleToFit(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Width, iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Height);
    doc.Add(pdfImage);
    doc.Close();
    doc.Dispose();
    //Delete image file after PDF created
    System.GC.Collect();
    System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    //imageData.Dispose();
    imageData.Dispose();
    if (File.Exists(ImagePath))
        File.Delete(ImagePath);
}
```

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with your "selenium-chromedriver" tag.

Comment: So what's is the solution? @ConradAlbrecht